# The multipart identifier "table.name" can not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got this problem. 
I have two or more Databases on diffrent Servers

When I try to get this statement to work I got the error. 
The multi-part identifier "Table.name" can not be bound.

```
    SELECT [per_id]
      ,[per_nummer]
      ,[per_pid]
      ,[per_name]
      ,[per_vname]
      ,[per_email]
      ,[per_instradierungHauptort]
      ,(SELECT TOP 1 [abteilung_kurz] FROM [Remoteserver2].[db_name2].[dbo].[t_alg_personalstamm] WHERE [Remoteserver2].[db_name2].[dbo].[t_sys_alarm].personalnummer = [db_name1].[dbo].[person].per_pid)
FROM [db_name1].[dbo].[person] 
WHERE per_pid LIKE ('F%') 
AND per_instradierungHauptort LIKE ('K%')
```

What I have to do to fix it?

Comment: The syntax is not correct. The `t_sys_alarm` table must first be joined to your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You select from `[t_alg_personalstamm]` but use `[t_sys_alarm]` in the where clause.

I think this line

```
(SELECT TOP 1 [abteilung_kurz] 
FROM [Remoteserver2].[db_name2].[dbo].[t_alg_personalstamm] 
WHERE [Remoteserver2].[db_name2].[dbo].[t_sys_alarm].personalnummer 
   = [db_name1].[dbo].[person].per_pid)
```

should be

```
(SELECT TOP 1 [abteilung_kurz] 
FROM [Remoteserver2].[db_name2].[dbo].[t_alg_personalstamm] 
WHERE [Remoteserver2].[db_name2].[dbo].[t_alg_personalstamm].personalnummer 
   = [db_name1].[dbo].[person].per_pid)
```

Comment: thank you alot. made my script faster without a join. now i can go on. :)